# FOSS for real-time PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, compiling, tools

Any [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSS) for real-time PGFPlots? Is it worth opening a feature request for KtikZ (QtikZ)?

Comment: Aehm... Excuse my ignorance, but: What is FOSS?

Comment: Maybe he means this kind of [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSS), but I'm not sure as well.

Comment: FOSS = Free and Open-Source Software

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tools which allow "what you see is what you get" output immediately while you type are independent of pgfplots: they are based on (la)tex and/or tikz (in the case of ktikz). Consequently, if you have a viewer which translates and views tikz files right away, they should work for pgfplots immediately.

This applies to any kind of "real time feature". In QtikZ (Ktikz) you can edit the template to include the missing packages,macros,libraries etc. (In Windows version admin rights are required to save the template). Here is a screenshot

[image]

If it turns out too be too slow: this would be a feature request for pgfplots because pgfplots takes its time.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to include an example if you don't mind.

Comment: Incredible how this awesome feature of KtikZ is hidden in the docs.