# kTikZ and extra packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, ktikz

Is there any way of loading extra libraries within KtikZ with the `\usepackage{}` command, like in other LaTeX documents?
I could not find any documentation.

And, of course, a MWE in this case is not possible.

Comment: Similar answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116123/foss-for-real-time-pgfplots

Comment: @tl017, is the answer satisfactory? Could you please accept it in the affirmative case?

Answer (score 14):

Click the `Edit` button and add any package you need to the template.

[image]

Mine follows for reference:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
<>
\end{document}
```

The `<>` mark is where the code you type in KtikZ will be placed.

Comment: Hello Juliohm, yes it works now. Many thanks for your help! tl017